# Худіти / схудіти / похудіти, худати / похудати чи худнути / схуднути?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, росіянізм, дієслова, словотворення

Як правильно називати дію, при якій відбувається втрата ваги?

1. На [цьому](https://life-pro.com.ua/uk/blog) сайті бачу формулювання:

   > ЗСЖ, правильне харчування і фітнес. Допомагаємо **худіти**!
2. [Тут](http://xvatit.com.ua/fitnes-vdoma/2016-fitnes-v-domashnix-umovax-dlya-divchat-top-5-variantiv.html) використовують таке слово:

   > Цілі можуть бути різноманітні: підтягнути м'язи по всьому тілу або в окремих зонах, **схудіти**, придбати гнучкість і легкість в суглобах...
3. У [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/pokhudity/) все ж зафіксовано такі варіанти:

   > **ПОХУДІТИ**, ію, ієш, ПОХУДНУТИ, ну, неш: мин. ч. похуднув, пула, ло і похуд, ла, ло; і **ПОХУДАТИ**, аю, аєш, док. Стати худим, худішим.
4. Виходячи з СУМу-11, вживають у недоконаному вигляді слово ["худати"](https://hejen.ru/uk/sekret-yak-%D1%97sti-bagato-i-sxudnuti-pyat-mifiv-pro-sxudnennya.html):

   > Секрет: як їсти багато і **схуднути**?
   >
   > Можна багато їсти і **худати**.
5. А [тут](https://dobre.stb.ua/ua/2018/07/09/kak-kushat-vse-i-hudet-sovety-dietologa-oksany-gerasimchuk/) використовують вже таку форму:

   > Як їсти все й **худнути**: поради дієтолога Оксани Герасимчук

Отже цікавить, яку форму правильно вживати, аби не було ототожнення з російським слово "худєть"? Можливо, нормативно усі форми використовувати або ж є такі, які слід уникати чи взагалі не правильно вживати?

Comment: У своєму четвертому пункті ви пишите, що робите висновок з СУМу-11, що можна вживати слово "худати", наводячи посилання на сумнівне джерело, в той час як СУМ не містить слова "худати". Поясніть, що ви маєте на увазі.

Comment: Так, наводжу. Але ж подаю усі варіанти, які фігурують в просторах Інтернету. Щодо сумнівності джерел, то посилалася на ті, які першими вискочили у Google. Таких надзвичайно багато, про що свідчить широке використання варіантів слова на позначення зниження ваги. Тому і питаю, що з цього дозволено. Зауважу, що СУМ-11 вже теж дещо "застарілий", тому, можливо, вже у новому СУМ-20 будуть корективи щодо цього слова. Проте поки що він лише до літери "М".